# How to apply discount using in App Purchase in ios

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, applepay, swift4.2

I am trying to apply discount for my digital content provided by app.

Let says User will get the discount coupon code/notification through server Coupon code will automatically gets filled with the code shared with the user in notifications/provided by server.

When user tries to apply any discount-Code then original amount is replaced by discounted one. and redirected to payment screen of ApplePay

Comment: In app purchase prices are set in App Store connect.  You could create a second IAP for the same item with the lower price and when the person uses a coupon they purchase that item instead of the other item

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for suggestion . Actually Multiple discounts coupons are provided in the app like 10% ,20% and so on . So looking for any other alternative .Please suggest :)

Comment: You can't vary the price of IAPs from the app; the price can only be changed in App Store Connect.

Comment: @Paulw11 this means we have to create multiple IAP as per discount rate provided to users to achieve this functionality

Comment: That is the only way, yes

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for valuable response. One more question Can you please give me example of any app that uses this discount feature functionality.(like any shopping app)... and can We achieve it by any #rd party SDK like stripe or any other payment gateway ?

Comment: Hi @Ruby did you find any solution?. did create multiple products for discount works for you?.does apple approve this approach?